# Daily chess self-training plan?

Tags: theory, training, online

Here I am asking suggestions on plans to systematically improve one's chess skills. I am aware of questions such as [this one](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1702/systematic-approach-to-learning-opening-endgame-theory), but I am seeking advice based on the following criteria:

1. I am willing to spend 30-60 minutes on chess everyday.
2. I am unwilling to spend money on this. Thus expenses such as paid membership or personal coach will not be an option. I have access to some libraries so books are welcome; I have regular access to the internet as well. Any recommendation of engines that are completely free will be more than welcome.
3. The training needs to cover all areas of chess playing, including of course opening, mid-game and endgame.

Here is what I am doing on a regular basis (all of them can be done for free):

1. Solve 5 puzzles at chess.com and 10 at 365chess.com.
2. Play one puzzle rush at chess.com.
3. Study one lesson at chess.com.
4. Watch some chess related videos on Youtube. (Since there are so many videos/channels/playlists, any recommendation will be appreciated.)
5. If time allows, I would also play a few 5+5 blitz games at chess.com for fun. I do not have much time to sit down and play some lengthy games, at least on a regular basis.

I currently do not have a rating but my estimation of my ELO rating is 1500-1600. I am also wondering if it is realistic for me to obtain the FIDE Master's title after say 10 years of self-training of 30-60 minutes per day.